# Programming a simple clock

Tags: java, datetime

Here's the start of some code for a clock that can display time in 24 and 12 hours.

What could be added to it? How could I can apply notions such as OOP, model and Enums here?

```
public Clock {
    private int time = 0;

    public int get24hrTime(){
        return time;
    }

    public int set24hrTime( int newTime ){
        this.time = newTime;
    }

    public int get12hrTime(){
        if( time - 12 < 0 ){
            return time;
        } else {
            return time - 12;
        }
    }

    public String get12hrPostfix(){
        if( hours - 12 < 0 ){
            return "AM";
        } else {
            return "PM";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Do not fix something that works", what is the issue with this code?

Comment: There is no functional issue with this code. It will get the green flag in TDD. But I am bothered by the design aspect. I just want to see how other programmers could design this more elegantly with comments on their reasoning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you check the time with `(hours - 12 < 0)`. This involves two operations, one subtraction and one compare. You could simply use `(hours < 12)`.

Also you rely that in the method `set24hrTime(int newTime)` the time is never > 23 for your code to work. Why don't you check this?

Also what about the value `0` for your hours? This must be displayed as `12 AM`. At the moment you return `0` in this case where it must be `12`.

Also for the value `12` of the hours you return `0` as value for the `12hrTime` which is wrong.

To sum up I would suggest the following code:

```
public Clock {
    private int time = 0;
    public int get24hrTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public int set24hrTime(int newTime) {
        if (newTime > 23 || newTime < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.time = newTime;
    }
    public int get12hrTime(){
        if (time == 0) {
            return 12; // Special case 0
        } else if (time <= 12) {
            return time;
        } else {
            return time - 12;
        }
    }
    public String get12hrPostfix() {
        if (time < 12) {
            return "AM";
        } else {
            return "PM";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the "throw new IlllegalArguemntExeption()" come from and what does it do?

Comment: The IllegalArgumentException is a RuntimeException of Java. You can throw this exception if you detect an illegal argument (e.g. a negative hour or an hour above 23).